# What stored procedure is Crystal Reports using to connect to my database?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm trying to make alterations to an existing Crystal Report form in a VB.net project I've inherited, and it's my first time using Crystal Reports. For clarity, I'm using Crystal Reports under Visual Studio 2010, not the standalone Crystal Reports.

I've had a good go at looking through all the functions and variables listed in the CR Designer, and can't find what stored procedure is being used to call for data.

Where do I look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open the report in the CR Designer
2) Right-click somewhere in the designer, select Database and then Set Datasource Location
3) From there, if you expand the Properties item next to the 'table' you want to know the source of, it'll show you what it's based on. You'll see something like 'Table Name:dsp_MyReport' or 'Table Name:Command'. If it says Command, right-click on the 'table' and choose View Command. Otherwise the name mentioned is the real source of the 'table'.